# The top part of the inner element is cut out and unreachable when using a css combination of `position:fixed;` and `display: flex;`

Tags: html, css

I'm building a fullscreen modal, and I'm trying to center the content vertically when it is smaller than the screen, and to start at the top and allow scroll, when the hight is larger than the hight of the container. I'm trying to use `position:fixed` to position the container on the screen, and `display:flex; align-items:center;` to center the inner div. When the container is shorter than the inner div the top part of the inner div is cut out, even when I use: `overflow-y:scroll`.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="inner-w">
      hello world 
      <div class="long-box">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.modal {
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 70px; 
  top: 0; 
  left:0; 
  right: 0; 
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  padding: 15px; 
  overflow: scroll;
}
.inner-w {
  margin: 50px 0; 
  width: 100%; 
}
.long-box {
  height: 400px; 
  width: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid brown; 
}
```

here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/benCarp/bh2Lfpo4/18/#&togetherjs=aKbe8NLJSR

Answer (score 2):

add to .modal{flex-direction-column;} now you can remove the margin

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 70px; 
  top: 0; 
  left:0; 
  right: 0; 
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center; 
  padding: 15px; 
  overflow: scroll;
}
.inner-w {
 
  width: 100%; 
}
.long-box {
  height: 400px; 
  width: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid brown; 
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="inner-w">

      hello world 
      <div class="long-box">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But why doesn't it work with `flex-direction: row;` as default when all I'm trying to use it for is center the element?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem. It does display the the top when the inner div is smaller than the container, but when it's smaller than the container it doesn't center the element.

Comment: add justfify-content:center;

Comment: `justify-content:center;` does center it, but than it cuts the top when the inner div is higher.

Comment: did you remove the align items?

Comment: you want the long-box items to be centered?

Comment: Thanks @godfather, this was really helpful!

Comment: I posted an ansewr, however after you adjust your answer I can select yours as the accepted answer.

Comment: but 1 question i saw that long-box is wrapped  by inner what if you use the flex on the inner instead of modal

Comment: no you solved the problem  so your answer should be accepted i was trying just to help

Comment: If I use flex on the inner instead, it won't be centered. I'm using flex to center the inner div. I tried similar solutions, and I think that If I use flex on the inner it won't center the inner div itself. Unless you do something like `height: 100%;` on it. Also then you have to add some more properties.

Answer (score 0):

@godfather had an excellent suggestion to change the direction of the flex container from row to column with `.modal{flex-direction-column;}`. It better describes our layout, and the width and margin property aren't needed any more. However it is not enough. `overflow: scroll` (or "auto") property isn't inherited, and should be placed on the actual element that overflows - the `.inner-w` class.

Here is how the css should look:

```
.modal {
  position: fixed; 
  flex-direction:column;
  bottom: 70px; // kept for a button 
  top: 0; 
  left:0; 
  right: 0; 
  display: flex; 
  padding: 15px; 
  justify-content: center; 
}
.inner-w {
  overflow: auto;
}
.long-box {
  height: 400px; 
  width: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid brown; 
}
```